# Extract a Contact's Mailing Country or User's Mailing Country on Case object

Tags: formula, formula-field, case, user-record

I am currently trying to extract either a Contact's mailing country or the User's mailing country onto the Case object. FYI : All our users are stored as contacts too.

I used a formula field with return type text : NULLVALUE(Contact.MailingCountry , Contact.User__r.Country ). Ideally it should display the Country from the User object if the Contact object's mailing country is blank but it does not.

Is there a better way or formula to achieve this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF(
   NOT(ISBLANK(ContactId)),
   Contact.MailingCountry,
   IF(
      NOT(ISBLANK(UserId)),
      User.MailingCountry,
      ''
   )
)
```

Althougth Salesforce continues to support NULLVALUE, BLANKVALUE has the same functionality as NULLVALUE, but also supports text fields.